# Erro ao executar programa em C

Tags: c

Tenho que criar um programa de cadastramento de filme, porém quando eu rodo o programa e ele da erro e eu não sei porquê não roda, podem me ajudar?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()

{
    struct informacao_sobre_os_filme
    {
       int ano_de_lancamento, faixa_etaria; 
       double duracao;
       char nacionalidade[200], nome_do_filme[200], genero[200];

    };

    struct informacao_sobre_os_filme;

    printf("CADASTRMENTO DE FILMES: \n");
    printf("Nome do filme: \n");
    scanf("%c", &nome_do_filme);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tem vários problemas no código apresentado.

- `%c` é para ler um caretere. Para ler uma string tem de utilizar `%s`
- A declaração de uma variável do tipo da estrutura `struct informacao_sobre_os_filme;` ficou sem o nome da variável.
- A estrutura deve vir declarada antes do `main` como é convenção e para que possa usada por várias funções.

Corrigindo tudo isso ficaria assim:

```
struct informacao_sobre_os_filme {
    int ano_de_lancamento, faixa_etaria;
    double duracao;
    char nacionalidade[200], nome_do_filme[200], genero[200];
};

int main(){
    struct informacao_sobre_os_filme filme1; //agora variavel chamada filme1

    printf("CADASTRMENTO DE FILMES: \n");
    printf("Nome do filme: \n");
    scanf("%s", filme1.nome_do_filme); //ler para o filme1 no campo nome_do_filme
    return 0;
}
```

Repare que como o `nome_do_filme` é um array de carateres, já é tecnicamente um ponteiro para o primeiro, logo não leva o `&` no `scanf`.

Se quiser pode até utilizar uma forma mais robusta de leitura que seria com o `fgets`. Com `fgets` consegue ler mais do que uma palavra e garantir que não lê mais que o espaço que alocou, que seria neste caso são `200` carateres:

```
...
printf("Nome do filme: \n");
fgets(filme1.nome_do_filme, 200, stdin);
...
```